# In the following sentence , should locally owned have a hyphen?

Tags: grammar, vocabulary, syntactic-analysis, phrase-meaning, hyphenation

In the following sentence , should locally owned have a hyphen?

A fun, causal way to sample the sights, stories and flavors of a cross-section of locally owned restaurants.

Comment: I think the accepted answer to the question *[Should I use a hyphen after -ly when modifying a verb in the past participle verb?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/155744/should-i-use-a-hyphen-after-ly-when-modifying-a-verb-in-the-past-participle-ver)* provides a general rule ("Do not use hyphens after adverbs ending in -ly") that answers your question ("locally owned" should not have a hyphen). Note that the use of hyphens is a matter of style, so different publications follow somewhat different rules.

Comment: No. ..................

Comment: Another relevant question is *[Should there be a hyphen in expressions such as “currently-available X”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/367316)* From Sven Yargs's answer there: "As a matter of style [...] opinion is remarkably consistent in condemning the hyphenated form."

Comment: Note also that most major dictionaries do not hyphenate **cross section** when it is used as a noun, as it is in your sentence. See the definitions in [OneLook](https://www.onelook.com/?w=cross+section&ls=a)

Answer (score 0):

If you look [here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/6-common-hypercorrections-and-how-to-avoid-them/hyphenating-ly-adverbs) you’ll see that **adverbs** ending with -ly aren’t hyphenated. When they are, it is called “hypercorrection.”