# Hyphenation of Compound Adjectives in Math

Tags: hyphenation, open-vs-closed-vs-hyphenated

I am interested in the rules concerning the spelling of some mathematical terms like "continuously(-)differentiable function" or "Lipschitz(-)continuous function".

As I understood (https://english.stackexchange.com/a/156008/177997), if the second word is a past participle, no hyphen is required. What are the rules in the aforementioned cases?
*Lipschitz is a surname, which in this case specifies the type of continuity (functions can be uniformly-, absolutely continuous etc.).*

Comment: *Continuously* needs no hyphen, as an adverb already makes its own connection.